# Do files in NSDocumentDirectory transfer when user upgrades iPhone

Tags: ios, nsdocumentdirectory

I have an app that saves user entered information to the NSDocumentDirectory. On issue that people are having is when they upgrade their iPhone to iPhone 5, the information in their old NSDocumentsDirectory are not being transferred over, even when they select the app to be transferred over.

Users end up loosing all their entered data when they upgrade.

When users upgrade the app on the same phone they do not lose their data. It only happens when they upgrade to a new iPhone.

What is the way to correctly save User data and make sure it is transferred over when the phone is upgraded?

Answer (score 0):

Data is only transferred to a new device if they choose to do a full backup of the old device and then choose to restore that full backup to their new device. Simply transferring apps results in fresh installs of the apps with no data.

This has always been a major problem with iTunes (and now iCloud backups). There is no way to backup a single app and its data and there is no way to restore a single app and its data. Only the app can be restored but no data unless a full device restore is done.

All of my apps have their own built-in features for backing up and restoring its own data. This allows users to easily transfer data between devices or deal with them messing up their own data by mistake.

Comment: Can a full restore be done between iPhone 4 and an upgraded iPhone5?

Comment: Honestly I don't know. I've never tried it. Though I believe iTunes gave me that option when I upgraded from an iPhone 4 to an iPhone 5 a couple of months ago. But I chose to setup up the iPhone 5 as a new device. It should work.